# What is the acceptable method for generating an auto incrementing primary key in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment

Is there no easy way to do this without sequences and triggers? I have average SQL skills, and I want to use the industry standard method for pl/sql (PostgreSQL). I'm basically converting over this example table from Spring Security:

```
create table group_members (
    id bigint generated by default as identity(start with 0) primary key,
    username varchar(50) not null,
    group_id bigint not null,
    constraint fk_group_members_group foreign key(group_id) references groups(id));
```

What I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE auth_group_members (
    id NUMBER,
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    group_id NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_AuthGroupMembers" FOREIGN KEY(group_id) REFERENCES auth_groups(id)
);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The standard way would be to use [`serial` or `bigserial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL):

> The data types serial and bigserial are not true types, but merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier columns (similar to the AUTO_INCREMENT property supported by some other databases).
>   [...]
>   Thus, we have created an integer column and arranged for its default values to be assigned from a sequence generator.

So you'd create the table with something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE auth_group_members (
    id bigserial primary key,
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    group_id NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_AuthGroupMembers" FOREIGN KEY(group_id) REFERENCES auth_groups(id)
);
```

The `serial` and `bigserial` types do create a sequences behind the scenes but you never have to work with the sequence directly.

Comment: The original table said `id bigint ...` so the better equivalent would be `bigserial`.

Comment: I thought it might be serial based upon what I was seeing in pgadmin, but every time I searched for serial, or plsql keywords in Google I would get a bunch of links for cracked software :( So a big thanks to you!

Comment: @hal100001: You might want to bookmark the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/manuals/), it is very good and even includes an index.

Answer (score 3):

In PostgreSQL 10 you can use `identity columns`. Here is example:

```
create table group_members (
    id bigint generated by default as identity(start with 1) primary key,
    username varchar(50) not null,
    group_id bigint not null
    );
```

Additionally:

1. Good article about [identity columns vs serial](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-10-identity-columns/).
2. PostgreSQL [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createtable.html) for more info (Ctrl+F and search "AS IDENTITY").